# Memory location of a std::condition_variable can cause futex error

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-alignment

We had a bug in our software that ended in the dreaded:

> The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.

We traced it down to a problem where the location of std::condition_variable within a malloc'd region of memory causes a futex error. If the std::condition_variable is not aligned on a 16 byte word - then it causes the futex error when you try to `wait`. In the example the first two `wait_for` calls work, but the last one aborts the program with the futex error.

```
void futex_error()
{
    /* init */
    std::mutex mtx;

    /* Normal one works  */
    std::cout << "Doing normal" << "\n";
    std::condition_variable* con_var = (std::condition_variable*)malloc(sizeof(std::condition_variable));
    new (con_var) std::condition_variable{};

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        con_var->wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    /* Clean */
    con_var->std::condition_variable::~condition_variable();
    free(con_var);

    std::cout << "Doing 16 bytes" << "\n";
    /* Works on 16 byte alignment  */
    uint8_t* ptr_16 = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(std::condition_variable) + 16);
    std::condition_variable* con_var_16 = new (ptr_16 + 16) std::condition_variable{};

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        con_var_16->wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    /* Clean */
    con_var_16->std::condition_variable::~condition_variable();
    free(ptr_16);

    std::cout << "Doing 1 byte" << "\n";
    /* Futex error */
    uint8_t* bad_ptr = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(std::condition_variable) + 1);
    std::condition_variable* bad = new (bad_ptr + 1) std::condition_variable{};

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        bad->wait_for(lck, std::chrono::seconds(1)); //<--- error here?
    }

    /* Clean */
    bad->std::condition_variable::~condition_variable();
    free(con_var);
}
```

I cant seem to find documentation on futex errors and why the alignment would cause this. Does anyone know why this would occur? This is on linux (Arch and Ubuntu) whilst using gcc 9.3.

Comment: What compiler and architecture are you hitting this error on?

Comment: `Does anyone know why this would occur?` Because accessing unaligned variable is undefined behavior? Did you expect it to work?

Comment: The last line of your function invokes `free(con_var)`,   but I'm pretty sure you meant to invoke `free(bad_ptr)`  Right?  I'm not sure if this is related to your issue because I can't repro any issue (yet).

Comment: @selbie Opps yer - never notice cause it doesn't get that far. Im on either Arch or Ubuntu and using gcc 9.3

Comment: Visual Studio likely won't repro because a `std::condition_variable` is wrapping its primary data structure with `std::aligned_storage` on that platform and toolset. Not sure about Linux, but are you compiling with `-std=c++11` or later enabled?

Comment: Using c++17. Yer I should of said that it works on windows for me.

Comment: I'm lookiing at the header for `condition_variable` on my Cygwin console.  It definitely doesn't look safe to do weird memory alignment things with this class.  So I'm with KamilCuk.   How did your original code get into this situation to begin with?

Comment: @selbie Ive fixed it - was just curious as why we had no problems arise with all other classes or on Windows. It occurs after something stores some type erased objects that contain condition variables. There was a very specific case where it stored it unaligned  for some buggy reason.

Comment: As I said before.  The Windows implementation of `condition_variable` appears to be using [std::aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to wrap the implementation's core data structure. `aligned_storage` basically fixes up the memory alignment issue to support your scenario.

Comment: Final comment - my best technical guess about "all the other classes" is that it's not a big deal for the alignment to be off.  However, `condition_variable`, like many other threading primitives probably relies heavily on atomic operations with the x86 LOCK prefix as the implementation. I can't find proof of this yet, but I suspect the target operand address of a LOCK instructions has be on a natural word boundary for its type.  In other words, x86 can't atomically increment an integer add an odd (not divisible by 4) memory address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the alignment would cause this

From [C++ draft Alignment p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#1):

> Object types have alignment requirements ([basic.fundamental], [basic.compound]) which place restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated.

The expression:

```
new (bad_ptr + 1) std::condition_variable{};
```

invokes undefined behavior on systems where `bad_ptr + 1` is not aligned to `alignof(std::condition_variable)`. Testing on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ABcJKa) with gcc10 the `alignof(std::confition_variable)` is equal to `8`.

Both `bad->` accesses are unaligned accesses and both are undefined behavior.

> Does anyone know why this would occur?

Inspecting `strace` output on execution of the executable, we can see that:

```
futex(0x557da3e262e9, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=2439, tv_nsec=619296657}, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Because `uaddr` first argument which should be a pointer to `int` of `futex` call is not aligned to `_Alignof(int)`, kernel detects it [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/kernel/futex.c#L480) and futex return `EINVAL`. The standard library just exits the application then, which is a perfectly fine behavior for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the source of my version of this *"The futex facility returned an unexpected error code."* error message.

It was simply caused by *#pragma pack(1)* without returning to normal packing in some other unrelated source code. Then std::condition_variable was initialized and it errored on use.